# Heart consumption notification while I'm not a Werewolf

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

At random times during gameplay (mostly after killing someone), I will get the notification saying that I just consumed a heart and that it contributed to my next Werewolf Point. Eventually it said that a new Werewolf Skill is available.

I read something similar can happen while being a Vampire when Serena is following you. I know it can't be that, because I still have Serena following me, and she's a Vampire. Also, since re-becoming a werewolf, I have not turned yet (I originally was a werewolf, but became a vampire for their quest line, and returned to being a werewolf afterwards).

So to recap, I am NOT in Werewolf form and I keep getting the *Heart consumed* notification.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The last paragraph sounds like a contradiction: apparently, you met the requirements you mention you read about.

Comment: Are you using mods?

Comment: No, I am not using mods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a bug since the beginning, **and there is no fix.**

The bug is probably due to erroneous delay of the messages, and, according to [Arthmoor](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/3363860-unofficial-skyrim-legendary-edition-patch/?view=findpost&p=48659387) (author of the unofficial patches, and general Creation Engine expert):

> It's an engine bug with no solution. I don't think anybody even knows
>   how to reliably trigger it, and we certainly can't fix it.

The bug [might](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/611z4h/bug_heart_consumed_message_in_human_form/) eventually fix itself (i.e. disappear).